# Combining columns in Pandas based on column header

Tags: python, pandas

I'm needing to merge columns in a dataframe.

The headers will have a similar name with a different suffix, e.g.

```
A1 | A2 | A3 | B1 | B2 | B3
```

I want to end up with all of them merged:

```
A | B
```

I have this line that successfully merges a defined set of columns into a single column:

```
df['A'] = df[['A1','A2','A3]].apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

The problem is that the headers are inconsistent in that there might be any combination of '1','2',or '3' - e.g.

```
A1 | A2 | A3 | B2 | C1 | C2
```

From the solutions I've looked at, pandas doesn't like to reference columns that don't exist, so I can't use `apply` statement as a blanket command.

I'm having trouble visualizing a solution beyond a list of nested Try/Except steps. If anyone has an idea, I would appreciate it!

**Update**
Thanks for the solutions!!! If anyone is interested, here's what worked for me:

*Solution 1*

```
for h in headers:
    cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.split('[')[0] == h]
    if cols == []:
        cols = [col for col in df.columns if col == h and col.split('[')[0] not in headers] `
```

*Solution 2*

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('[').str[0],axis=1).agg(lambda x :' '.join(x.values.tolist()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the df.columns attribute to find the relevant columns

```
a_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col[0] == 'A']
```

then use that list as the input for your apply function

```
df['A'] = df[a_cols].apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Comment: This worked well in a for loop with just a little tweaking to (1) split on a specific character and account for values that were already added. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For example you have following dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A1':['a'],'A2':['b'],'B2':['b'],'B3':['c']})
```

We using `groupby` on columns

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str[0],axis=1).agg(lambda x :','.join(x.values.tolist()))
Out[282]: 
     A    B
0  a,b  b,c
```

Comment: I like this one, but (unclear in my example) the headers may be different lengths, e.g. [ 'apple' , 'apple[1]' , 'lime[1]' , 'watermelon' ]. Is there a way to split on a character (e.g. left square bracket) rather than an index or slice?

Comment: @JRM change to `df.columns.str.split('[').str[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A1', 'A2','A3', 'B1','B2','C1'])

new_cols = {}
for new_col in list(string.ascii_uppercase):
    new_cols[new_col] = [col for col in df.columns if new_col in col]

for new_col in new_cols.keys():
    df[new_col] = df[new_cols[new_col]].apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```